# Asymptotics of recursion

Tags: recurrence-relations, asymptotics, recursion

suppose we have the following two sequences

$$\alpha_k = (k-1)\left(1-\frac {1}{1+(k+1)l}\right)  \quad , k \geq 2$$
$$\beta_k  = (k-1)\left(1+\frac {1}{1+(k-1)l}\right)  \quad , k \geq 2$$

where $l$ is a positive constant
and define the sequence $c_k$ recursively by:
$$c_2 = - 1/\beta_2 $$
$$c_3 = 0 $$
$$c_{k+1} = \frac{\alpha_{k-1}}{\beta_{k+1}}c_{k-1}    \quad , k \geq 3        $$

it is not hard to see that this would give 
$$c_2 = - 1/\beta_2$$
$$c_{2k} = -\frac{\alpha_2}{\beta_2  }\cdot\frac{\alpha_4}{\beta_4  }\cdot\cdot\cdot \frac{\alpha_{2k-2}}{\beta_{2k-2}  }\cdot \frac{1}
{\beta_{2k}}  \quad , k \geq 2$$

$$c_{2k+1} = 0  \quad , k \geq 1 $$

apparently we must have $d_k = c_{2k} \sim k^{-(1+1/l)}$ but I have no idea how to show this. can anyone shed some light on this?

also a similar question for the recursion
$$c_2 = - 1/\beta_2 $$
$$c_3 = \frac{\gamma_2}{\beta_3}c_2  $$
$$c_{k+1} = \frac{\alpha_{k-1}}{\beta_{k+1}}c_{k-1}  + \frac{\gamma_k}{\beta_{k+1}}c_k       \quad , k \geq 3     $$

where 
$$\gamma_k = \sigma  \frac{l(k^3-k)}{1+kl} \quad , k \geq 2$$
$\sigma$ being also a positive constant

How would the asymptotics look like in this case?